# Getting Distinct value in Python

Tags: python, mysql, list, distinct

I have a list

```
[<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 46L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 2L}>,
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>,
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 46L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 2L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 46L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 2L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 46L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 2L}>, 
<Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>]
```

I want the distinct value of this 
Expected Result is

```
[
 <Storage {'CaseID': 45L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 3L}>, 
 <Storage {'CaseID': 46L, 'PatientProfile_ID': 2L}>
]
```

This data is being pulled from Database. Please don't advice me to use the DISTINCT keyword on the database. Its been sorted by another column. Using distinct will remove the sorted result.

Can it be done in python. Or do i have to write a for loop to do the same thing?

MyCODE

```
entries=db.query("SELECT cases.ID as CaseID,PatientProfile_ID FROM \
                             `callog` ,consultation,cases WHERE callog.Consultation_ID=consultation.ID and consultation.Case_ID = cases.ID and \
                             Doctor_ID="+str(Id)+" ORDER BY callog.CallDate DESC")
            rows=entries.list()
            return rows
```

Comment: `set(ur_list)` operation would work.

Comment: @TanveerAlam That will not guarantee the order of the items

Comment: @thefourtheye: See my code. Thats how webpy returns a resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should handle things nicely.

```
def remove_dupes_keep_order(seq):
  seen = set()
  seen_add = seen.add
  return [ x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
```

Using `seen_add` speeds up the operation.

See also, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order).

Since the issue seems to be that your items are of type `Storage`, try this:

```
def remove_dupes_keep_order(seq):
  seen = set()
  seen_add = seen.add
  return [ x for x in seq if not (json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True) in seen or seen_add(json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True)))]
```

Comment: Nope, <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /doctor
unhashable type: 'Storage'

Comment: Ah, well that's crappy. Are you using the features of the `Storage` object? Or can you convert it to a standard Python dictionary?

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat, I've updated my answer to provide an alternative possibility.

Comment: No much on the net, Its only said that Storage is a Fancy type of Dictionary :(

Comment: I didn't see much either, but perhaps you can convert it back with `dict(i_am_a_storage_object)`.

Comment: For the Second Version of "remove_dupes_keep_order" i got <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /doctor
unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat, it turns out you cannot put a dict in a set, so I convert it to a JSON representation which can be used in a set. This should work now, I believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71947/discussion-between-abhilash-cherukat-and-richard).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newList = list(set(oldList))
```

above, turns your list into a set (which removes duplicates) and then back into a list.

For more information: Refer [this](http://mattdickenson.com/2011/12/31/find-unique-values-in-list-python/). See, if that helps.

Comment: Nope,<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /doctor
unhashable type: 'Storage'

Storage part is the problem with both the answers.

Answer (score 0):

After all the trial and error, I am back to For loops

```
def remove_dupes_keep_order(self,seq):
        Lister=[]
        for row in seq:
            Dicter={"CaseID":row["CaseID"],"PatientProfile_ID":row["PatientProfile_ID"]}
            Lister.append(Dicter)
        seen = []
        seen_add = seen.append
        return [ x for x in Lister if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
```

Snippet Courtesy: @Richard

Comment: This has a for loop  you can use the accepted answer coz of a better solution it is.